# .htaccess file to nginx configuration file

Tags: file, .htaccess, configuration, nginx

I really need to convert this .htaccess code to nginx configuration. I have never worked with nginx, so I am pretty new to this kind of stuff.
My .htaccess is not that big. If anyone could convert it to a nginx configuration file, it would be great!

```
<Files file.swf>
   ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

(I have tried to use the converters which have been previously posted, but none of them seemed to work.)
Thanks in advance,
Zoorah.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "file" in "file.swf" represents a file name, then ...

```
location ~ file\.swf {
    default_type application/x-httpd-php;
}
```

Comment: It did not really work. I now receive a 404 Not Found error when trying to access the file.